# Elasticsearch stops working suddenly

Tags: linux, indexing, elasticsearch

I am running Elasticsearch on a VPS and it was working perfectly for me. Initially, there were many rows indexed using Elasticsearch. When i tried to create new index, Elasticsearch stopped working. Now whenever i try to start Elasticsearch, it works for some time and then it gives me message "Killed" and it stops working. I deleted the new index that i had created and tried  to start Elasticsearch but it still gives me the same error. Any solutions to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs? check the elasticsearch.log in the logs folder where elasticsearch is installed.

Comment: I checked the log files and i saw that it was giving something like this:

[org.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.support.HealthMonitorThread] Waiting for cluster (100 minutes elapsed)...
[org.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.support.HealthMonitorThread] Waiting for cluster (101 minutes elapsed)...

Comment: How many nodes do you have? Did you add any new node? when you add a new node, the elasticsearch takes some time to come into green state. Check the cluster health status of es server using the curl command curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'

Comment: Number of nodes are 2.
When i fired this command it is showing me status "red"
But when i fired this command to check cluster status of my index(curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health/index_name?pretty=true') it is showing me status "yellow".

Answer (score 0):

Most common thing which could be happening in your case is OOM (out of memory) is getting triggered for your elasticsearch java process if this is linux , trying checking /var/log/messages and dedicate Heap based on your server compute power.